# How do I stack multiple subplots (10+ subplots)

Tags: python, matplotlib

Currently I am attempting to plot 57 graphs. Each graph has two data sets. I am trying to figure out how to plot them and have them stacked, however it seems if I hit 3 subplots I get

```
ValueError: num must be 1 <= num <= 2, not 3
```

So it would seem there is some sort of limit on number of plots allowed? Is there another way I can do this?

```py
    for k, v in tests.items():
    print("Building graphs for " + str(k))
    i = 1
    while i <= v:
        print("Building graph for Config " + str(i))
        cur.execute('Select Iteration, Download, Upload From Ookla_Client where Config = ' + str(i) + ';')
        db_return = cur.fetchall()
        x = []
        for test in db_return:
            x.append(test[0])
        y = []
        for test in db_return:
            y.append(test[1])
        y2 = []
        for test in db_return:
            y2.append(test[2])
        plt.subplot(2,1,i)
        plt.plot(x,y,'.-')
        plt.plot(x,y2,'.-')
        plt.title('Config 1')
        plt.xlabel('Test')
        plt.ylabel('Mb/s')
        plt.legend(['Download', 'Upload'], loc='upper right')
        plt.grid()
        i += 1
```

Comment: If you use `subplot(2,1,i)` then there are only two subplot "slots" available. See [`subplot`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html)

Comment: Yup you got it, I was misusing subplots, thank you for setting me straight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subplot function uses 3 parameters: `subplot(x,y,n)`, with `x` being the number of rows, `y` the number of columns and `n` the position of your current plot. So by using `subplot(2, 1, i)`, you're telling Matplotlib that you want 2 subplots (one above the other). What you want to do is either input the value by hands to have a grid. I made a function back then to automatically compute the optimal values of `x` and `y` in order to have a square display (or what would be the closest to a square):

```
size = len(my_array_of_values)

final_x = 0

for i in range(10):
    if pow(i,2) < size:
        final_x += 1

final_y = ceil(size / final_x)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(final_y, final_x, sharex=False, sharey=False)
```

Then you would access your different subplot by using this: `current_axis = axs[floor(i/final_x)][i%final_x]`, `i` being the number of iterations you've currently made. Let me know if it works for you, of if I misunderstood what you wanted to achieve.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you, I was misusing subplots. I will also checkout your code snippet and see if it may help out my current situation even more.